# Uploading an UIImage to AWS S3 through Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: python, ios, google-app-engine, amazon-s3, google-cloud-endpoints

We are using the GAE Python SDK 1.9.4 with Google Cloud Endpoints, on an iOS client. We serve images to our users from buckets on AWS S3, and are interacting without problems from iOS, to GAE, to AWS through the `boto` library.

The specific use case we are reaching for is allowing our users to update their avatars. On the appserver, we have unit tests which successfully compute and upload image data to S3 from files, as well as their base64 string representations, and return URLs for client consumption. The file sizes range from a few kilobytes to several megs. The unit tests cover the boto controller, as well as the endpoints.api wrapper that calls it. We have tested with base64 strings originating from the python `base64` library, as well as the `GTLBase64` tool on iOS. The strings are web-safe. From iOS, we force the image to be a 160x160 JPG with maximum compression, which consistently yields a base64 string of approximately 3K.

This is the protorpc message class:

```
class AvatarUploadRequest(messages.Message):
    uid = messages.StringField(1)
    avatar = messages.BytesField(2)
    content_type = messages.StringField(3)
```

Through the appserver unit tests, we successfully assign the image data to the `avatar` `BytesField()`, send the payload to boto, and can then view the S3-hosted image in a browser.

Our problem arises when trying to interact with the avatar upload endpoint through both the API explorer and generated iOS client. The API server constantly fails with an `503 Service Unavailable`, using known-good data that we use in the unit tests. The API server is operational, all other calls complete successfully.

For the Avatar Upload endpoint only, the API explorer returns the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "backendError",
            "message": ""
        }],
        "code": 503,
        "message": ""
    }
}
```

Removing the `avatar` payload from the POST request body removes the error. The code in the @endpoints-decorated method executes. With the `avatar` payload, execution fails upstream of our implementation (ie. none of the code in the method is run).

Have we hit a limitation of the Endpoints API server? 
Are we not supposed to use it in this fashion?

Scouring the docs, there is no mention of an upper limit to the `BytesField()` size. There is mention of using the Blobstore API for larger files (video, image etc.) but it doesn't fit our use case; we don't want to store the image data on AppEngine, in the datastore or otherwise, we just need to funnel it through our appserver and forward it along to S3.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to follow-up on this, with what we put in place to work around it.

There seems to be a hard upper limit to the binary data allowed to be uploaded through Google Cloud Endpoints. We didn't dig deep enough to find where it's enforced, instead, we decided to extract a module whose only responsibility was to talk to AWS, and define new endpoints using another framework.

For arguments' sake, we opted to wrap the new module's endpoints with the Flask microframework, and manage upload of binary data to AWS through the boto library. The same data that fails in the original post above through Cloud Endpoints now works 100% through Flask.